# Linux serial port - wrtie( ) byte to the target device through serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

```
unsigned char cmd[] = {'A', 'T', '+', "0x07", "0x08", 'D', 'F', "0xA6"};
```

To write this command to my target device, I expect to write byte

```
41 54 2b 07 08 44 46 A6
```

accordingly.

However, the actual bytes written to device are

```
41 54 2b b8 bb 44 46 be
```

and it's obvious wrong at

```
0x07 0x08 0xA6
```

How to write bytes are I expect to have in the above example ?

----- write function -------

```c
void WriteToDevice(){
unsigned char cmd[]={'A', 'T', '+', "0x07", "0x08", 'D', 'F', "0xA6"};
int n = write(fd,&cmd,8);

for(p=0;p<8;p++){
    printf("bytes written: %02x \n", cmd[p]);
}

if(n<0){
    printf("write error \n");
}
else{
    printf("%d bytes written \n", n);
}

};
```

compiler warning

```c
warning: (near initialization for ‘cmd[3]’) [enabled by default]
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Comment: How are you expecting someone to help, you must post the code that is writing the wrong data.

Comment: @iharob what else you need to know about my question ?

Comment: The code, it's not possible to know why it's writing the wrong data if I don't see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"0x07", "0x08"`, etc use `'\x07', '\x08`', etc.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your way but the printing out bytes still not what I expect, did I do anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. Although it would be ok `'\x07'` -> `0x07`.

Comment: @Sam, you should enable compiler warnings, your initialization of the `cmd` array is wrong.

Comment: I just tried `unsigned char cmd[] = {'A', 'T', '+', '\x07', '\x08', 'D', 'F', '\xA6'};` and `unsigned char cmd[] = {'A', 'T', '+', 0x07, 0x08, 'D', 'F', 0xA6};` -- they both work as expected.

Comment: @Sam, NEVER IGNORE COMPILER WARNINGS AGAIN. SPECIALLY IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT THEY MEAN.